# my jsonarray does not show in my arraylist

Tags: java, android, json, list, android-volley

I've got the jsonArray but it does not show in my list. I have added all the needed xml files.

My volley is working and I have a response with the jsonarray, but my problem is that it's not show in the list.

```
// json array response url
private String urlJsonArry = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_array.json";

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


// Progress dialog
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public AppController app ;


// temporary string to show the parsed response
private String jsonResponse;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.array_list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txt, (List) items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    makeJsonArrayRequest();
}

private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    showpDialog();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);
                                items.add(person.getString("name"));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    person.getString("name"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    app.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}

private void showpDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hidepDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

So please can you help me showing my jsonarray in my arraylist?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after your JSON parsing loop.

i.e

```
                     for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);
                                items.add(person.getString("name"));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    person.getString("name"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```